# Override TalkBack gestures

Tags: android, view, accessibility, gestures, talkback

I have a Input Service and View in it. I need to override some gestures for ExplorationByTouch: e.g.: I want to turn off the double click. Here's a part of code, where I want to do that. Any idea how?

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        final int action = e.getAction();

        switch (getActionMasked(action)) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: { // Processing the first touch
            // Index of the first pointer always equals to 0
            final int firstIndex = 0;
            final int identifier = e.getPointerId(firstIndex);

            setPressed(true);
            sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
            Log.d("Pressed", "Press first finger");

            final Stroke firstStroke = Stroke.newInstance("first");
            strokes.put(identifier, firstStroke);
            firstStroke.append(Point.valueOf(e.getX(), e.getY()));

            anotherHandScheme.onFingerTouch();
            mainHandScheme.onFingerTouch();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: { // Processing of the second touch
            final int index = getActionIndex(action);
            final int identifier = e.getPointerId(index);

            // We ignore the third and the following touches
            if (identifier > 1)
                break;

            setPressed(true);
            sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);

            final Stroke secondStroke = Stroke.newInstance("second");
            strokes.put(identifier, secondStroke);
            secondStroke.append(Point.valueOf(e.getX(index), e.getY(index)));

            anotherHandScheme.onFingerTouch();
            mainHandScheme.onFingerTouch();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final Set<Integer> identifiers = strokes.keySet();
            for (Integer id : identifiers) {
                final int index = e.findPointerIndex(id);
                final Point newPoint = Point.valueOf(e.getX(index), e.getY(index));

                if (!newPoint.equals(strokes.get(id).lastPoint()))
                    strokes.get(id).append(newPoint);
            }

            anotherHandScheme.onFingerMove();
            mainHandScheme.onFingerMove();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: { // Processing of the second touch
            final int index = getActionIndex(action);
            strokes.remove(e.getPointerId(index));

            anotherHandScheme.onFingerGone();
            mainHandScheme.onFingerGone();
            setPressed(false);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // All fingers leave the screen surface
            strokes.clear();
            anotherHandScheme.onFingerGone();
            mainHandScheme.onFingerGone();
            setPressed(false);
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Explore by touch's double-tap detection takes place before your app gets a chance to process the events. You can't override it.

Comment: @BrendanMcK, here's a [Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gif73nkez3vvfyr/Russia%20goes%20innovations.mp4) that show how application should work. You see it'll very difficult to enter text with double tap...

Comment: @BrendanMcK UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction is for iOS, isn't it?

Comment: @alanv thank you for answer! So there's no way to get around the double tap, isn't there? I think it will be not very correct try to turn off EBT programmatically in my app?

Comment: You also cannot programmatically turn off Explore by Touch. So no, there is no way to disable or avoid the double-tap gesture.

Comment: @Padmelina - d'oh! You're right; that's what I get for staying up late working at an iOS issue; now *everything* looks like it's iOS to me! Odd that Android doesn't (yet?) seem to have a comparable feature, though...

Comment: @BrendanMcK ha) it's okey) Now I try to use another screen reader programm, may be I can do what I need)