# Disable exploration-by-touch for custom view

Tags: android, view, accessibility

Can I programm disable android exploration-by-touch only for my view (for all whole system it should be work). If no, is there some methods to avoid ebt double-touch, but save announcing?

Comment: No, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933475/override-talkback-gestures). What do you mean by "save announcing"?

Comment: @alanv, thank you, it's very pitty for me. If I turn off explore by touch at my device, it stops announsing through annonceByAccessibility. May be you know screen readers which don't need EBT?